# Why does react routers can't handle predefind route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In App.js component I was defined route like this:

```
      <Route path="/item/:itemId" exact element={<Item />} />
```

But when I manually enter the URL in the browser like :

```
http://example.com/item/3
```

The browser shows me an error page:

```
404 - File or directory not found.
```

How can I fix the error?

Comment: is this working fine in development? if yes, the issue is most probably with the server you're using

Comment: Seems the server hosting your app needs to be configured to redirect all requests to nested routes/pages to your root `index.html` file.

Comment: Yes it seems it related to iis

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it.

According to this [article](https://inthetechpit.com/2019/06/13/handle-client-side-routes-with-iis-on-page-refresh-react-app/), I should install the URL Rewrite module first. then
create a web.config beside project build files. and put these inside it :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="ReactRouter Routes" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url=".*" />
              <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
            </rule>

          </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

So now my problems solved

Answer (score -1):

If you are using router v6 there is not `exact` keyword

Comment: `exact` isn't a keyword, it's a prop, and while yes, RRDv6 `Route` components don't use an `exact` prop, React will safely ignore extraneous props.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).